# Where can I view the code for the built-in Python method id() (Python 3.x)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpython, python-internals

Where can I view the code for the built-in Python method id() (Python 3.x)?

I've been searching for it on Python's GitHub page, but am not having any luck. I've looked at other questions related to this, but could not find the specific method id().

Thought I'd see if anyone here knows where the code for that method is.

Comment: Maybe here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1173 but why do you ask?

Comment: We don't need a separate question for each individual function; the duplicate includes an answer referencing `bltinmodule`, which contains `id`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like most built-in names, the `id()` function is defined in the [`Python/bltinmodule.c` source file](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2d53bed79c1953390f85b191c72855e457e09305/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1156-L1178):

```
static PyObject *
builtin_id(PyModuleDef *self, PyObject *v)
/*[clinic end generated code: output=0aa640785f697f65 input=5a534136419631f4]*/
{
    return PyLong_FromVoidPtr(v);
}
```

This uses the [Python C-API function `PyLong_FromVoidPtr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_FromVoidPtr) to turn the address of the Python object referenced by the pointer `v` into a Python `int` object (using a [system-specific cast to a C `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long` integer first](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2d53bed79c1953390f85b191c72855e457e09305/Objects/longobject.c#L1017-L1032))

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful! I'm trying to mark this as the answer, but it says I have to wait. I will mark it asap.